# Moving data from SQL database to an array in JavaScript via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Ive been trying this for hours now but it wont quite get there.

I have a database which amongst other things contains geocodes, lat and lon. I have accessed these using the following PHP

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "tompublic", "public") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("first_section") or die(mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT geo_lat, geo_lon FROM first_page_data")
or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
$lat[] = $row['geo_lat'];
$lon[] = $row['geo_lon'];
}
?>
```

These values in `$lat` and `$lon` then need to be put into an array in a javascript function like so:

```
var latit = [];
var longi = [];
latit = '<?php echo $lat[]; ?>';
longi = '<?php echo $lon[]; ?>';
```

But it wont work! Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't latit just equal `Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var latit = <?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>;
var longi = <?php echo json_encode($lon); ?>;
```

Edit: Also, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var latit = [<?php echo implode(",",$lat) ?>];
var longi = [<?php echo implode(",",$lon) ?>];
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is first try to switch to MySQLi due to the fact that Mysql is depreciated.

But try

```
var latit = <?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>;
var longi = <?php echo json_encode($lon); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are created using a comma separated list surrounded by brackets

```
var latit = [];
```

To use your PHP values

```
var latit = [<?PHP echo implode(",",$lat); ?>];
```

This assumes your values are numbers. If not, you'll need to include quotes.

```
var latit = ['<?PHP echo implode("','",$lat); ?>'];
```

Finally, [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) is a good option as many of the other answers indicate.

Comment: what does 'implode' do?

Comment: Implode is the same as join, it takes an array and joins the items together with the glue, in this case a comma: http://us3.php.net/function.implode

Answer (score 0):

You can either do as @Robbert stated

OR
Using php `json_encode` convert it to JSON string and you need to `JSON.parse()` it to convert it to javascript object

```
 var latit = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>");
 var longi = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($lon); ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "tompublic", "public") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("first_section") or die(mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT geo_lat, geo_lon FROM first_page_data")
 or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
$lat[] = $row['geo_lat'];
$lon[] = $row['geo_lon'];
}
 echo '
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  var latit  = '.json_encode($lat).';
  var longi  = '.json_encode($lon).';
 </script>
';
?>
```